# What the difference between linux-tools virtual / generic / euclid / etc?

Tags: apt, kernel, performance, benchmarks

Trying to install `perf` (to count CPU cycles and events when I run a certain program). I used `sudo apt install linux-tools`

```
Package linux-tools is a virtual package provided by:
  linux-tools-oem 4.13.0.1026.30
  linux-tools-gke 4.13.0.1015.17
  linux-tools-gcp 4.13.0.1015.17
  linux-tools-euclid 4.4.0.9027.28
  linux-tools-virtual-hwe-16.04-edge 4.15.0.20.42
  linux-tools-virtual-hwe-16.04 4.13.0.41.60
  linux-tools-virtual 4.4.0.124.130
  linux-tools-lowlatency-hwe-16.04-edge 4.15.0.20.42
  linux-tools-lowlatency-hwe-16.04 4.13.0.41.60
  linux-tools-lowlatency 4.4.0.124.130
  linux-tools-generic-hwe-16.04-edge 4.15.0.20.42
  linux-tools-generic-hwe-16.04 4.13.0.41.60
  linux-tools-generic 4.4.0.124.130
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

I guess I'll need one of the 4.4.0* to match my kernel version. But I could not find documentation about generic / virtual / euclid /low latency and the hwe flavors. What are they ? Which one will be the most compact and will provide just `perf`

**Reference**

https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

Comment: I would guess you are running kernel 4.4.0-124-generic, in which case you would want linux-tools-generic. It is just my opinion, but I do not think it matters much which version of perf you get (I use `perf` compiled from the kernel.org source tree (actually I tend to use primitive trace commands instead of perf)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linux-tools` are used for the kernel performance evaluation and related to the particular version of the kernel.
The *kernel update policy flavours* description is provided in the [Ubuntu RollingLTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack):

- `ga`  - General Availability, a standard Ubuntu kernel with the *fixed version*
- `hwe`  - HardWare Enablement stack, indicates an incremental rolling updates of the kernel (the *versions vary* in time)
- `hwe-edge`  - early access to the upcoming HWE Stack, can be thought as an experimental *hwe* for the final testing before the global release

Ubuntu provides *2 kinds (flavours) of the kernel*, the informal brief description is:

- `generic`  - standard kernel recommended for majority users, it aims to optimize overall scheduling performance in the multi-process and multi-threaded execution environments but does not provide any guarantees for the maximal scheduling delays
- `lowlatency`  - specialized kernel with the near real-time execution of the processes and guaranteed limits for the maximal scheduling delays